# Dropdown menu with Bootstrap alignment

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I'm doing a dropdown menu with bootstrap. I basically copy the code from the documentation and add my text. The thing is that the dropdown set itself to the right, going off the screen. If I add a "dropdown-menu-right", it aligns to the right and it shows the full square, but the layout design I'm trying to do is centered on the menu item.

My HTML:

```js
/*let rols = ["rol1", "rol2", "rol3"];
    
let rolsText = rols.map((rol, index) => {
  return (
      <li><a className=' text ' id={index} href="#">{rol}</a></li>
  );
});*/
```

```css
.setting-box {
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.settingImg {
    width: 40%;
}

.user-box {
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.userImg {
    width: 40%;
}

.logout-box {
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.logoutImg {
    width: 40%;
}

.text {
    font-size: 12px;
}

.dropdown-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<div className='dropdown-container'>

<div className="dropdown">  
    <a className="dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" ><img className='settingImg' src={settingsImg}></img></a>

    <ul className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <li><a className='text' href="#">Cambiar contraseña</a></li>
    </ul>
</div> 

<div className='dropdown'>
    <a className="dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" ><img className='userImg' src={userImg}></img></a>

    <ul className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
        {rolsText}
    </ul>
</div> 
</div>
```

Also, there is an image of the problem, in case I didn't explain myself well:

[image: dropdown problem]

And the code where this Menu ("MenuOptions" component)is inserted:

```
<div className='header-container'>
            <div className='brand'>
                <img src={logo} className='img-logo' id="img-logo" alt="logo" />
                <div className="name" id="name">
                    <p>
                    <strong className="letterBlue">e</strong>strong-
                    <strong className="letterBlue">B</strong>ased{" "}
                    <strong className="letterBlue">B</strong>eats
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <MenuOptions/>
        </div>
```

Comment: Hi, Can you show the HTML where the main buttons are set?

Comment: Problem is not like you are mixing html : `class` with reactjs: `className` ? Just set everything in `className`

Comment: Hi @RicardoSanchez. Sure! I'm going to edit the general questions. Thanks!!!